# safardriver closes automatically before driver.close() is called in @Aftermethod

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I'm running below test scripts in safari browser version 5.1.7 on windows 7.

After running **@test** method I'm calling **driver.quit()** in @aftermethod. But safari browser is closing before it reaches @aftermethod and throws **java.lang.NullPointerException** error. Due to this new safari browser instance is not opening after browser is closed. How to resolve this issue?how to override the safari shutdown? Below is the execution log

```
  public class Test{
            WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeMethod
        public void init()
        {
            driver = invokeSafariDriver();
        }

    public static WebDriver invokeSafariDriver() throws InterruptedException
        {
            //logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launching Chrome driver");
            System.out.println("Launching Safari driver");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return driver;
        }

        @Test
        public void launch
        {
            driver.get("www.google.com");
        }


      @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            try{
                System.out.println("Closing the browser");
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Closing the Browser");
                driver.quit();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                driver.close();

            }

        }

Dec 01, 2016 4:54:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 7469
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1 operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Driver connected in 3408 ms
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Closing connection
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@c540f5a
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
Dec 01, 2016 4:54:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod closeBroser
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.betawoohoo.Example.closeBroser(Example.java:289)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
```

Comment: Where's the test code?

Comment: in test method i'm just opening browser and in beforemethod i'm instantiating safaridriver like WebDriver driver = new Safaridriver();

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question as well.

Comment: Code updated :)

Comment: how does `launch()` and `tearDown()` even know what `driver` is??

Comment: i have created driver as global variable and assigned safari instance to driver variable and ran the same suite. The issue is after launch is executed safari driver is closed by itself and exception will be thrown when the execution reached tearDown method since there is no safari browser is opened so that it can be closed.

Comment: I doubt the code provided by you and the stacktrace do not relate. Trying to infer from `java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.betawoohoo.Example.closeBroser(Example.java:289)`. Also I can't see in the current code provided that the driver is a global variable!! Please provide optimal details to get the help in the matter. The question is currently of Very Low Quality. You might want to go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: updated full code..let me know for any more clarifications

Comment: the code wouldn't still compile. Try doing that. You also can't get an exception in `Example` class `closeBroser` method with this updated code.  `com.test.betawoohoo.Example.closeBroser(Example.java:289)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129595/discussion-between-praveen-ps-and-nullpointer).

Answer (score 1):

You should define Webdriver outside the `init()` method so that it can be accessible in other methods also.

```
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()
    {
        driver = new SafariDriver();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void launch
    {
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: exception occured in Aftermethod since the browser is closed automatically by Safaridriver. You can check my log where safaridriver closing the connection and shutting the browser. The main issue i'm facing is "Safari browser closes by itself before driver.quit() is called"

Comment: Why are you defining `WebDriver` again in `invokeSafariDriver()` method, Remove WebDriver Try with below code`System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            driver = new SafariDriver();`

Comment: update the `inti()` method with below `public void init()
        {
            driver = invokeSafariDriver();
        }`   and `public static void invokeSafariDriver() throws InterruptedException
        {
            //logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launching Chrome driver");
            System.out.println("Launching Safari driver");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            driver = new SafariDriver();
            ......
            Thread.sleep(2000);
           // return driver;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize WebDriver instance first and then use it

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void init()
{
    driver = new SafariDriver();
}

@Test
public void launch
{
    driver.get("www.google.com");
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class Test{
        public WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeMethod
        public void init()
        {
            invokeSafariDriver();
        }

    public static void invokeSafariDriver() throws InterruptedException
        {
            //logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launching Chrome driver");
            System.out.println("Launching Safari driver");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            driver = new SafariDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //return driver;
        }

        @Test
        public void launch()
        {
            driver.get("www.google.com");
        }


      @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            try{
                System.out.println("Closing the browser");
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Closing the Browser");
                driver.quit();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                driver.close();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only change driver name inside your fun invokeSafariDriver() , so as following :

```
  public class Test{
            WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeMethod
        public void init()
        {
            driver = invokeSafariDriver();
        }

    public static WebDriver invokeSafariDriver() throws InterruptedException
        {
            //logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launching Chrome driver");
            System.out.println("Launching Safari driver");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            WebDriver driver1 = new SafariDriver();
            driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver1.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return driver1;
        }

        @Test
        public void launch
        {
            driver.get("www.google.com");
        }


      @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            try{
                System.out.println("Closing the browser");
                logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Closing the Browser");
                driver.quit();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                driver.close();
   }   }
```

This to keep you code structure as it , but I recommend to use pom (Page object mode) as a Pattern/Structure with following link:

https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html